# Cusstomising ckeditor adding or removing buttons

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I tried to install ckeditor gem for my laptop. It Somehow didnt work for me. So I downloaded the ckeditor and used it in my project.

Does anyone know how to customise the ckeditor? I want to know where I can edit the buttons for the ckeditor??

For example I want to remove the image upload and flash buttons. Also i want the last Line of options to open on hovering a button.

Answer (score 0):

By Usng the below code you can add or remove the buttons.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_id', {
    toolbar: [
    { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates' ] }, // Defines toolbar group with name (used to create voice label) and items in 3 subgroups.
    [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ],          // Defines toolbar group without name.
    '/',                                                                                    // Line break - next group will be placed in new line.
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] }
]
});
```

You have to do some modification in the plugins. Like to change for "Cut" option in your ckeditor/plugins/ you will have `clipboard.js` file. There for `cut` button you have to change the code from `onclick()` to `mouseover()`.